# There is an error when I try to install virtual box into Ubuntu

Tags: installation, virtualbox

When I tried to install virtual box in Ubuntu it showed up an error. It says

```
dependency is not satisfiable: lib 9th - network (<>=4:4.5.3)
```

Please let me know how to handle this error.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please add few more info about how you are installing and what is the command. In which step are you getting the error?

Comment: please add more info. `lib 9th` doesn't seem to be a valid name. You can copy command and its full output.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you are using the .deb download).

Use the following command to install virtualbox (It will automatically download vbox and all dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt
```

It will prompt you for your password, then for confirming installation (just enter y).