# Virtual Box Setup Error

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, oracle

I downloaded Virtual Box and installed it. I followed instructions on how to set it up but when I went to run it I got the following errors on the right side of the image below ↓

[image]

I tried the `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt` advise from here: → [There is an error when I try to install virtual box into Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232517/there-is-an-error-when-i-try-to-install-virtual-box-into-ubuntu) and got the following read out:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   virtualbox-qt is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I also tried the: `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` advise in the top error report and got this read out: `"bash: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory"`

Can someone instruct me on what I should do to fix this problem?

**"EDIT" ↓**

After a complete new install of Ubuntu 12.04 this morning, I followed NikTh's advise and downloaded Oracle’s Virtual Box V-4.2 from the link he provided. Set it up and tried to run it. I did not have an ISO (lost in the computer crash last night) so I booted it from CD/DVD drive, with the same Live CD I used to re-install this morning... This is the problem I have now, (above the cursor). ↓

[image]

Can someone please explain why Ubuntu 12.04 will run on my laptop but not on my Virtual Machine? Am I missing some settings somewhere?

**"UPDATE"**

I finally got Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit, to run in my Virtual Machine, so it is working properly...

My Final question is this - If Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version runs on my laptop how come it does not run in my VM?

Thank you, "NikTh" & "Terry Wang" for your patience and all your help...

Comment: Did you reboot ? Reboot and if you still have problems, try to execute the command again (root privileges needed) `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

Comment: Does `/etc/inti.d/vboxdrv` actually exist? It is a shell script.

Comment: @NikTh I did what you suggested and rebooted, had the exact same result as before. I also did `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and got the same result also... Thank you for trying though...

Comment: What version of virtuabox have you installed ? Are you sure that you don't have installed and mixed up the two versions ? I mean the Oracle's version with OSE version ? Lets try these commands now and see `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install dkms` and `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` if the result is the same, try `sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox-ose start`

Comment: On the last one only? what about `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` ? What this returned ?

Comment: I never faced a problem like this before. I have installed VB in more than 10 Ubuntu (or Ubuntu-based) systems. I cannot suggest something else except to completely remove any VB package `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-*` and then download the Oracle's version from [here - Linux Hosts](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install it again.

Comment: @NikTh Thank you for all your advise and help. Computer crashed last night and I had to do a complete re-install. I am up-dating the system now and when finished I will download Oracle's Version and let you know how it turns out... Again, thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

The last updated image "This kernel requires x86_64 CPU but only detected an i686 CPU" indicats that you are trying to run a 64-bit Linux guest but your host does NOT support VT-x or AMD-V.

Please run this command to make sure your CPU is capable of Intel VT-X or AMD-V

```
egrep -wo '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Example on a Core i5 CPU

```sh
$ egrep -wo '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
vmx
vmx
vmx
vmx
```

Make sure 2 things

- VT-x or AMD-V is enabled in HOST BIOS
- In the VM settings - System Acceleration - tick Enable VT-x / AMD-V

Comment: I checked everything you said. The System Acceleration Tab was darkened and I could not open it. As far as the commands you gave, I ran them and got nothing... All this did make me remember that I accidentally (forgetting to get the 64 bit version) downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit. I tried the Virtual Box with that Live CD and everything worked just fine... Thanks for the help Terry...

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs everytime you upgrade your Host machine's Kernel.

As the error states run "sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup" from a terminal session and you can then start your Virtual machine from there.

As I mentioned you will need to do this after each kernel upgrade.